# Compound quantifiers

Tags: quantifiers

So basically there's a mathvideo in which there are some examples about compound quantifiers, but of which the answer is not provided. So I have no clue that I'm right or wrong, could someone please check my answers? Thank you in advance.

ex.1: ∀y∃x(x<y)
"For all y there exist at least one x such that x < y"
True because: x = y - 1

ex.2 ∃x∀y(x<y)
"There exists an x such that for all y (x<y).
False because: x=x

ex.3 ∀x∀y(x<y)
"For all x, for all y (x<y)"
False because: x<x

ex.4 ∃x∃y(x<y)
"There exists at least one x and one y such that (x<y)
True because: x < y + 1

Comment: Which set do $x,y$ belong to?

Comment: If the domain is real numbers or integers, then those are are all correct.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I meant their T/F answers are correct.  If that's not what you're meaning, then here's a formalized [Lean](https://leanprover-community.github.io/) proof: https://gist.github.com/kmill/0db5b6dd5afecd654d990fc64d61f09a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to keep in mind the domain of $x,y$. While all your answers are correct for, say real numbers, they may not be correct for $x,y\in\Bbb Z_{\ge1}$. The statement $(1)$ will then be false because there is no element in $\Bbb Z_{\ge1}$ smaller than $y=1$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast reply, very much appreciated :)

Comment: You are welcome!